# Spring integration: How to post request params with http outbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to call a REST web service through Spring Integration, i.e. Spring Integration will act as my client to the REST web service. However, I should add params to ws url and add json object as a param.
For this I tried the following configuration:

```
<int:enricher input-channel="inputChannel" request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel">
    <int:property name="info" expression="payload"/>
</int:enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="quakerHttpGateway"
    request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" 
    url="http://ffff.ff/gg/rest/put/{tel_number}"
    http-method="PUT" 
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" 
    charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="5000" 
    reply-channel="quakeinfo.channel">
   <int-http:uri-variable name="tel_number" expression="payload.getNumTelefono()"/> 
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

tel_number is not passed as a param and Can you please give me a solution to pass param as string through url and a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "tel_number is not passed as a param" ?

I just modified the [http sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/http) thus:

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway" 
             service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.RequestGateway"
             default-request-channel="requestChannel">
   <int:default-header name="content-type" value="application/json" />
</int:gateway>

<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" 
                           url="http://localhost:8080/http/receiveGateway/{tel_num}"
                           http-method="POST"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="tel_num" expression="'foo'" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

and it worked as expected - server side, I see

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/http/receiveGateway/foo]
```

It's not clear what you are asking about JSON; if you send a POJO in the payload and set the `content-type` header to 'application/json' (use a header-enricher) and put the Jackson jars on the classpath, it will just work.

Comment: How to pass {tel_num} ? It is a dynamic variable. I should pass it programatically. And the endpoint is not a Gateway but an inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: It doesn't matter what starts the flow; as I said in the asnwer, you can use a `<header-enricher/>` to set the `content-type` header. Your expression should work (if it's valid), I just used a literal expression. I need to know what you mean by "is not passed".

Comment: it does mean: how populate the URI variables {tel_number} , I send it in the header ?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want; if it's a property on your payload then `payload.numTelefono` will work. If you add it as a header, use `headers['numTelefono']`.